# How to make toggleClass jQuery work when elements are in separate divs?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to create a show/hide toggle button using jQuery. It seems to work, until I close the div that the button is within, making the two elements in different divs.

For example, the below works:

```
<div class="col span_1_of_3">
    <button class="reveal">Show Filters</button>

    <div class="filter-hide">
        <p>CONTENT</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this code does not:

```
<div class="col span_1_of_3">
    <button class="reveal">Show Filters</button>
</div> <!-- THIS CLOSING DIV HAS BEEN ADDED -->

<div class="filter-hide">
    <p>CONTENT</p>
</div>
```

JQuery is as follows:

```
$(".filter-hide").hide(); 
$("button.reveal").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle();

    if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Show Filters') {
        $(this).text('Hide Filters');
    } else {
        $(this).text('Show Filters');        
    }

    return false; 
});
```

Can anyone tell me why this is and how to fix it? The reason I am doing this is because I need the button to be 1/3 of the page and then the content to show full width below. I can work around it but then come across other problems.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `next()` to get to the another button, closing the div on the 1st button no longer makes it available. So that you can target the div no matter where you put it on, use the following:

```
$("button.reveal").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $('.filter-hide').slideToggle(); //Change here.

    if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Show Filters') {
        $(this).text('Hide Filters');
    } else {
        $(this).text('Show Filters');        
    }

    return false; 
});
```

Comment: Note, this will only work if you have a single `button.reveal` and `.filter-hide` - which appears to be the case in *this* scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You can traverse up to parent div using [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) then use `.next()` to target its sibling.

```
$("button.reveal").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('div').next().slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    //Rest of code
});
```

```js
$("button.reveal").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('div').next().slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass("active");

  //Rest of code
  if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Show Filters') {
    $(this).text('Hide Filters');
  } else {
    $(this).text('Show Filters');
  }

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col span_1_of_3">
  <button class="reveal">Show Filters</button>
</div>
<!-- THIS CLOSING DIV HAS BEEN ADDED -->

<div class="filter-hide">
  <p>CONTENT</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `.next()` which gets the next *sibling*. As it's no longer a sibling, it no longer finds it.

Your best bet if the control/content are in separate locations is to pair them up.  You can do this with a class or a `data-` attribute, eg:

```
<div>
    <button class="reveal" data-content='filter1'>Show Filters</button>
</div>

<div class="filter-hide" data-filter='filter1'>
    <p>CONTENT</p>
</div>
```

Then your button click code would be:

```
$("button.reveal").click(function() {
    var filter = $(this).data("content");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    $(".filter-hide[data-filter=" + filter + "]").slideToggle();
```

Using the pattern, you can add/remove buttons and content and never have to change your javascript to handle them individually and, more importantly, you won't need to change your javascript if you change the HTML again, which you would have to if you used any form of traversing (eg .closest().next().find() would work if this scenario, but not if you changed the html).